# mdDialog promise is not resolved when I hit Enter

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I am using md-dialog directive which is placed inside a form and contains submit button:

```
<form ng-submit="save()">
    <md-dialog aria-label="Title" ng-cloak>
        ...
        <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
            <span flex></span>
            <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" type="submit">Save</md-button>
            <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" type="button">Cancel</md-button>
        </md-dialog-actions>
    </md-dialog>
</form>
```

This is how I show the dialog. The code is placed in my AppCtrl:

```
    $scope.showDialog = function () {
        $mdDialog.show({
            controller: 'PopupCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'Popup',
            clickOutsideToClose: true
        })
        .then(function (args) {
             console.log(args); //this line is not called when I hit Enter on my keyboard
        });
    };
```

There is save() method inside the PopupCtrl:

```
    $scope.save = function () {
        $mdDialog.hide('It works!');
    };
```

When I click the Save button with my mouse, everything is working right, means the dialog is hidden and I can see the message in the console output.

**The issue is**: when I hit *Enter*, the dialog is hidden, but the line to output the message into the console is not called.

Note: the save() method inside the PopupCtrl is called in both cases.

**UPDATE**: Here is the demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cHpsumhOUb0IZpeLGJpj?p=preview)

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: is the fokus on an element inside your form?

Comment: Yes, it is. The focus is in the first textbox. I enter a value and then hit Enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to nest `<form ng-submit="save()">` inside the `<div class="md-dialog-content">` (instead of the one you have several levels above) and use `ng-click="save()"` instead of `type="submit"` within the "save" `<md-button>`.

See this demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tn9xZWVa42kLprbRQcay?p=preview)